# Scheduled Task and Android UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to periodically updated a ListView in a ListActivity. I know I can do this easily with an AsyncTask subclass, but out of interest I thought I'd look at using a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and the android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable action) method.

I release I may be having a 'senior moment', but problem is I can only seem to get it to work by nesting runnable, as both ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate and runOnUiThread require a Runnable as a parameter.

Here is my working code:

```
private void setUpPageUpdater()
{
    listUpdaterExecuter = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_LIST_UPDATER_THREADS);
    listUpdaterExecuter.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PageUpdater1(), 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

class PageUpdater1 implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new PageUpdater2());
    }
}

class PageUpdater2 implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        updateList();
    }
}

    private synchronized void updateList()
{
    pages.clear();
    pages.addAll(RetrievedPageProvider.getInstance().getPages());
    sortList();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Is there a nicer way to code this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: You don't need to synchronize `updateList`. It's performed on a single thread anyway.

Example with anonymous instances:

```
private void setUpPageUpdater() {
    listUpdaterExecuter = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(NUM_LIST_UPDATER_THREADS);
    listUpdaterExecuter.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        private Runnable update = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateList();
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(update);
        }
    }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the synchronized comment - I had added that when I was thinking it would be called by a separate thread, which of course it can't be as it touches the UI.

Comment: I tend to feel anonymous classes sometimes look a bit 'untidy', but in this case the nesting looks a bit nicer, so thanks for the code sample.

Comment: Hmm, that's a personal taste. E.g. I would never define an own class for a touch listener... But there's one thing to consider: Anonymous instances always keep a reference to the outer class. That could lead to memory leaks.

Comment: Interesting... so in your code sample, the Runnable passed to scheduleAtFixedRate will always have a reference to the ListActivity? Is it the same for nested classes?

Comment: In your example too... As long you have a inner non static class or an anonymous class, it will. Thats the reason why you can call the ListActivity methods in that class. Such an instance can't exist without a reference to the outer class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there is a better way to do this. Let's say you're using a CursorAdpater to display things in your ListView. Then every time you update your dataset, you can call [notifyChange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#notifyChange%28android.net.Uri,%20android.database.ContentObserver,%20boolean%29) (from any thread), and all CursorAdapters who have cursors on the particular URI you're updating will update what they display.

I realize you may not be using a CrusorAdapter. But there should be a synonymous way to do this for whatever adapter implementation you're using.

Comment: I'm using an array adapter and calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); when a task has completed on a list item triggered by a user action, but in this case I want to periodically update the list from a separate thread.

Comment: And in that seperate thread you can't update the array adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: I can update the array adapter, but the call to notifyDataSetChanged causes a problem. There is no exception or any useful info in logcat, but after calling the notify method the thread hangs at futuretask$sync.innerRunAndReset. I spotted this in the stack trace when stepping through the code so I added a try catch and logged the exception which stated that I could not touch the UI from the non-ui thread, or words to that effect.